# 'WebException' error on back button even when calling 'void' async method

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I have a windows phone app that allows the user to interact with it. Each interaction will always result in an async WCF call.
In addition to that, some interactions will result in opening the browser, maps, email, etc...

The problem is that, when hitting the back button, I sometime get the following error
`"An error (WebException) occurred while transmitting data over the HTTP channel."`

with the following stack trace:
`at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.OnGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8(Object state2)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
   at System.Threading.Timer.ring()`

My understanding is that it's happening because my app opened another app (browser, maps, etc) before it had the time to execute the `EndMyAsyncMethod(System.IAsyncResult result)`. Fair enough...

What's really annoying is that it seems it should get fixed by cloning the server-side method, only making it `void` with the following operation contract `[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]` but I'm still getting the error.

What's worse is that the exception is thrown in a system-generated part of the code and, thus, cannot be manually caught causing the app to just crash.

I simply don't understand the need to execute an `Endxxx` method when it's explicitely marked as `OneWay` and `void`.

---

**EDIT**

I did find a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680411/wcf-isoneway-is-not-behaving-like-it-is-oneway-operation). It does seem that it is related to the message getting to the service (not the client callback). My next question is:
if I'm now calling a method marked `AsyncPattern` and `OneWay`, what exactly should I be waiting for on the client to be sure the message was transmitted successfully?

This is new service definition:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, AsyncPattern = true)]
IAsyncResult BeginCacheQueryWithoutCallback(string param1, QueryInfoDataContract queryInfo, AsyncCallback cb, Object s);

void EndCacheQueryWithoutCallback(IAsyncResult r);
```

And the implementation:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginCacheQueryWithoutCallback(string param1, QueryInfoDataContract queryInfo, AsyncCallback cb, Object s)
{
        // do some stuff
        return new CompletedAsyncResult<string>("");
}
public void EndCacheQueryWithoutCallback(IAsyncResult r)
{
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code, how the web service is being called

Comment: Thanks for your reply Shiraz. I'm using the auto-generated proxy on the client so the code doesn't have much about it: MyProxy.CallWebServiceMethod(param1, param2);

Comment: I added some code to my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that will guarantee that message has been **delivered** for One-Way binding is turning on reliable messaging and ensuring that there are no communication errors (wrong address, binding, etc.) This is the list of bindings that support reliable messaging:

```
basicHttpBinding   - RM not supported

wsHttpBinding      - RM supported, not default

wsDualHttpBinding  - RM implicit

netTcpBinding      - RM supported, not default
```

For example for tcpBinding:

```
<binding>
    <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="MyTcpBinding">
            <reliableSession enabled="true" />
        </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
</binding>
```

Or:

```
<customHttpBinding>
   <binding configurationName="customReliableBinding">
      <reliableSession ordered="true" />
   </binding>
</customBinding>
```